# TransactionBuilder and add_from_inputs

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

Looking through the cardano-serialization-lib I see a `TransactionBuilderConfig` and a `TransactionBuilder` constructor that looks like it takes the Config and exposes `add_from_inputs` that *maybe* does the coinSelection that is in a separate module in projects like Nami.

I don't however see how that's exposed in the javascript. Am I missing and/or misunderstanding these things or how they could or should be used??

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

It should be right there just as you say. The *add_inputs_from* function on the *TransactionBuilder* takes the *strategy* as the second parameter.

So in Javascript if your using this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs), you can import from it the CoinSelectionStrategyCIP2 and pass a strategy to the tx builder like this:

```
txBuilder.add_inputs_from(utxos, CoinSelectionStrategyCIP2.LargestFirst)
```

The implementation of the strategies is here: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/6a8c67a0fdb2ac6d72132d9693b87a6734f3fed5/rust/src/tx_builder.rs#L329

Comment: Ok cool thanks I'll try it out maybe I was looking at it wrong